# Как анимировать иконку?

Tags: html, css

как вот тут https://toccata.com.ua/

у меня на фидле сейчас не совсем так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
 <div class="services__item">
   <div class="services__icon">
     <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/9/446/w512h5121380376664MetroUIPhone.png" alt="pic1">
   </div>
   <p class="services__title">Консультаційні послуги</p>
 </div>
```

```html
 <div class="services__item">
   <div class="services__icon">
     <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/9/446/w512h5121380376664MetroUIPhone.png" alt="pic1">
   </div>
   <p class="services__title">Консультаційні послуги</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: посмотрите библиотеку https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/, тут много эффектов и возможно есть нужный вам - вы можете его использовать просто указав соответствующий класс или выдрать только нужный css код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.services__icon img {
  transition: .3s;
}
.services__icon img:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="services__item">
   <div class="services__icon">
     <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/9/446/w512h5121380376664MetroUIPhone.png" alt="pic1">
   </div>
   <p class="services__title">Консультаційні послуги</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: когда уводить курсор, то не такое. В этом суть

Comment: или мне кажется? не совсем понимаю

Comment: @olyaromanenko, вы можете откорректировать мой код. в css свойство transform задает на сколько градусов вращать, свойство transition - за какое время вращать. Значения заданные мной в моем коде соответствуют значениям в коде сайта, которые вы дали для примера.

Answer (score 1):

Например:
HTML:

```
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
```

Это будет розворот
А например можно через класс:
HTML:

```
    <i class="fa fa-spinner"></i>
```

CSS:

```
    .fa-spinner {
      color: red;
      -webkit-animation: rotate 4s infinite linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
      from {
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
      }
    }
```

[Пример](https://spiner-font.vova2020.repl.co)